# Edit list item in blackberry cascades QML

Tags: listview, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have successfully created a list view that populates a json file which I have created now I'm trying to edit the list view item. But I'm having trouble doing it, I keep getting error ***TypeError: Result of expression 'curData' [undefined] is not an object***. Below is a sample code where I'm trying to edit the listview after the page is created.

This is the page where I load the list view

```
import bb.system 1.0
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.data 1.0
import Network.Communication 1.0
Page {
    Container {

        id: profilePage
        layout: DockLayout {
        }

        ListView {
            id: profileListView
            dataModel: contactsData
            listItemComponents: [
                ListItemComponent {
                    id: myItem
                    type: "item"
                    CustomListItemProfilePage {
                        id: listCell
                        background: Color.create(ListItemData.color)
                        text:  ListItemData.name 

                        onClicked: {
                    console.log(listCell.text);

                        }
                    }

                }



            ]

            onTriggered: {

            }

        }

    }
    onCreationCompleted:
    {
        var curData = contactsData.data([0,0])
        curData.name = curData.name + " : "+ _settings.getValueFor("loginUserName", "No login name");
        contactsData.updateItem([0,0],curData)
        console.log("on compleete LOADED:"+contactsData.data([0,0]).toString());
        profileDataSource.load();


    }
    attachedObjects: [

        GroupDataModel {
            id: contactsData
            sortingKeys: ["order"]
            grouping: ItemGrouping.None
        },
        DataSource {
            id: profileDataSource
            source: "asset:///Model/ProfileDetails.json"
            onDataLoaded: {
                contactsData.clear();
                contactsData.insertList(data);
            }
            onError: {
                console.log("JSON Load Error: [" + errorType + "]: " + errorMessage);
            }
        }


    ]


}
```

This is my sample json file. I'm trying to replace the text NAME with actual name that I get after login which is stored in _settings.getValueFor("loginUserName", "No login name")

```
[
{ "order": 1, "name": "NAME" ,"color":"#16A085" },
{ "order": 2, "name": "FIND FRIENDS" ,"color":"#2ECC71" },
{ "order": 3, "name": "INVITE" ,"color":"#3498DB" },
{ "order": 4, "name": "EDIT PROFILE" ,"color":"#34495E" }
]
```

This is the qml for my listview item

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import QtQuick 1.0
import "Model/floatConstants.js" as Item

Container {
    property alias text: label.text
    property TextStyleDefinition textColor:label.textStyle
    signal clicked() 

    layout: DockLayout {
    }
    preferredHeight: Item.itemHeight
    preferredWidth: 1000.0
    Container {
        background: Color.Transparent
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        Container {
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center

            Label {
                id: label
                text: "demo"
                textStyle {
                    base: textColor.style
                }

            }
            gestureHandlers: [
        TapHandler {
            onTapped: {
                clicked();
            }
        }
    ]
        }
    }

}
```

I'm new to blackberry and this is my first blackberry project. Please let me know if this is possible or if there is any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```
var curData = contactsData.data([0,0])
```

At this point contactsData does not have data yet, you haven't loaded it yet. First call

```
profileDataSource.load();
```

I'm not sure why you would use ListView for such thing though.

Comment: I tried to set curData after loading profileDataSource.load() but it still shows same error. What other method do u suggest Bojan?